# About the AirPlay feature in iOS5

Tags: ios5, airplay

As is known to all, the iOS5 has AirPlay feature to let the iPad2 out put the screen in the TV. There is a game(RealRacing 2 HD) which enable this feature to make the 3D graphic to output on the tv and 2D graphic still display on iPad. How can this game do that? The game' demonstrate is [here](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/17/dual-screen-airplay-gaming-demo-with-real-racing-2-hd/)

How can I out put my game like Real Racing 2 HD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok， I will answer my own question.
All I have done is follow the sample on [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Introduction/Intro.html)

When airplay function is ON， the UIScreen will auto generate a external screen, we can manage the EAGLView, separating some to add to the external screen and others add to main screen.

Hope my exp can help some one.

Comment: Do you consider airplay enabled device like Apple Tv as an external device in that way? Could you give a more detailed example?

Comment: @loretoparisi There is a example on [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Introduction/Intro.html)  You just need to create two framebuffer and renderbuffer if you want to separate the render like RealRacing 2HD. Then bind buffers which you need to use.